# Condition that returns false if image has certain name?

Tags: php

I need to make a condition with PHP that checks if an image is called "forums.citrix.com" and returns true if it doesn't.

The image is displayed with this code:

```
<img style="padding:4px; width:16px;" src="http://getfavicon.appspot.com/http://<?php echo "$urlhost[0]"?> />
```

I don't know how to do it with php. Or maybe it has to be done with javascript. How could I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Your src attribute is not syntactically correct. Remove the quotes and add a semi-colon. Also, an image isn't "called" something. Are you talking about the hostname in the URL of the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($urlhost[0] == 'forums.citrix.com')
  return false;
else 
  return true;
```

Make sure that you sanitize the image file name if it's based on user input.